# Ruby on rails installer issue in windows 7 pc

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.0

I just have installed in my windows machine form [`railsinstaller.org`](http://railsinstaller.org/).

Now earlier I have already installed in my machine `Ruby2.0`. So when I am trying to run the below command from the command prompt [as mentioned here](http://railsinstaller.org/windows):

```
rails s
```

getting error as :

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not f
nd 'railties' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `g
m'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Now if I uninstall the `Ruby2.0` things are set. But I want also to be workable in my pc the latest version of Ruby,so that I can run my practice ruby programs as I could earlier. - Please instruct me ,so that I can run my Rails and only ruby programs from my `Sublime Text 2` editor without impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the installer from this site: http://rubyinstaller.org/
After it installs, install ruby by opening the command prompt and typing:

```
gem install rails
```

that should install rails and its dependancies. From there you can just run the rails command and create projects like usual.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should have a look at https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/ to manage different ruby versions. I think, that the main problem you got is simply, that the PATH-settings for both rails versions (1.9.3 used in railsinstaller and 2.0) are interfering.